# Download Excel file in IE 11

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer, download, extjs4.1

I have this ExtJS code which is for converting a grid data into Excel format and write to a file, the code will ultimately export the grid data into downloadable Excel file. This works great in firefox and chrome but fails to function in IE browser (IE 11).

on analyzing found that the code will ultimately post below string onto URL box which will download the excel file.

```
data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,<base64 encoded string follows here>
```

at first, I thought problem might be somewhere in the code, then i happen to check below steps.
if i paste below content either in chrome or firefox, it prompts for file download and downloads a dummy file.

```
data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,blahblahblahblahblah
```

however if i paste the above same string in IE 11, it does nothing. So i am on the assumption that code is working fine but i may have to do something more to make it compatible for IE browser. But i dont know what else i could try.

any pointer is deeply appreciated.

below is my ExtJS code, if it helps.

```
    //here xmlString has the constructed xml string which holds 
    //grid column headers + grid rows with Table, Column, Cell and Worksheet tags.

    var ctx = {
        created : (new Date()).getTime(),
        worksheets : xmlString
    };

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">' + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>BlahBlah</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>' + '<Styles>' + '<Style ss:ID="columnHeader"><Font ss:Size="11" ss:Bold="1" /><Interior ss:Color="#CCFFCC" ss:Pattern="Solid"/> </Style>' + '</Styles>' + '{worksheets}</Workbook>',
        base64 = function(s) {
             return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
    },
        format = function(s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
            return c[p];
        });
    };

    var workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);
    var link = document.createElement("A");
    link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
    link.download = sheetName + " Level Report - " + Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s') + '.xls';
    link.target = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

PS: I have tried this on both ExtJS V4.1 and V6.0 but same behaviour.

Comment: Don't assume, hit F12, and be sure.

Comment: I checked in debugger console, it doesnt show any error when i try step by step debugging. When the controller reaches link.click()   it will just open a new tab with url populated with same string as mentioned in the post. Anything specific i should check or look for?